# Can I upgrade Node.js using command line in Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, yarnpkg

Is it possible to update `node` using command line/PowerShell in **windows 10**?

Surely, I can download the latest version from the official site and install, but, I'm hoping for a way to do it from `cmd`.

Right now, I've `npm` and `yarn` installed on my system if that helps.

Comment: try `npm install nvm` package. Hope it will serve your purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) is what you are looking for.

After installing [this](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases) program on your computer, you will be able to use `nvm` command (Node Version Manager) in windows command line and manipulate with node.js versions.

Commands that you probably need are:

`nvm install latest`: To install the latest stable version

`nvm list available`: Show a list of versions available for download.

`nvm use <version>`: Switch to use the specified version.

More information [here](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows)

Comment: another installer to avoid node installer :(

Comment: Windows cmd doesn't have default tools to manipulate with this. The only way is to install needed tool. For example, nvm-windows. After installing you can use the command in cmd like `nvm install latest [arch]` to upgrade node version.

Comment: @Bryan Hi, please, explain to me what exactly should I post as an answer? Should I copy a part of tool github README file here for "at least"? And what should I post here for **not** "at least"?

Answer (score -1):

Since you have **npm** you can use this command in powershell:

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

If you want documentation to refer to you can use:
[npmjs documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)